# Books on medical imaging

Tags: image-processing

As the title suggests , I'm looking for good books on medical imaging . It would be a great help if you can provide a link to the books website .

Thanks.

Comment: This can be very opinion-based... and most sites in the SE network don't like questions that result in "lists" of answers.

Answer (score 3):

I quite like the [Medical Imaging Signals and Systems](http://www.mypearsonstore.com/bookstore/medical-imaging-signals-and-systems-9780130653536) by Jerry L. Prince and Jonathan Links. If you're looking for a DSP approach to medical imaging, this is a good start. It's also quite good on the physics of medical imaging. the format of the book follows one medical imaging modality at a time. It first teaches you the *relevant* physics of how the imaging itself works for that modality, and then goes into the signal processing side of things in the following chapter.